# Problem with octal buffers

Tags: digital-logic, buffer

I have a bunch of random IC's from electronic goldmine and one of them includes the [MM74HCT541](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MM74HCT541.pdf) octal 3 state buffer.

So just a simple circuit to test it, I have 4x AA batteries and I am hooking this up on a breadboard. I hook up power to pin 20, and ground to pin 10, I then hook up power to A1, which is pin 2, and I hook up an LED with resistor from Y1 (pin 18) to ground. The LED does not light up. I tried it with other buffers in the IC, but it still didn't work. I have about 3 more of these, but just in case I was burning it out, I didn't want to try the others. So I am wondering what I am doing wrong here and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your setup?

Comment: Still tinkering I see ... keep it up.  If you can, maybe invest in a stable power supply, it will help you learn faster when you're not fixing problems not directly on topic. Although there is learning in that too...  You could also use a "wall wart" supply, but they are not well regulated and maybe not as safe as a proper power supply.  Maybe visit an old timey local electronics shop and get an old 500+ lbs power supply for $20 ?  ( I exaggerate about the 500 lbs....)

Comment: Thats a good idea except there aren't too many good electronic stores in the denver area of Colorado ( the best is RadioShack, and thats not good at all) except for this place called Fistels electronics but they are really mean to kids like me and don't tell me anything about stuff and they just are like "no it cant do that" when it really can, its so stupid

Comment: @skyler if you've got a supportive adult to go with you to those stores you can usually get the sales critter to fall in line. It is unfortunate but a LOT of adults see learning as useless and would rather just try to sell big-ticket items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pins one and 19 need to be low.  Also the max operating voltage is 5.5v, not 6v.  It is also a good idea to tie unused inputs somewhere like gnd.